# UITextView changing width screws up word wrap

Tags: ios4, uitextview

While writing a UITextView control, I realized that if I change the width (via setFrame) of the view on scale gesture, the word wrap gets screwed up. It becomes prominent on rescaling multiple times.

By screwing up, I mean that the text starts wrapping from a smaller frame/rectangle than the current width of the textview. This is what I am doing on scale gesture:

```
[textview setFrame:CGRectMake(textview.frame.origin.x, textview.frame.origin.y, textview.frame.size.width * [gestureRecognizer scale], textview.frame.size.height )];
```

Also, if it helps to debug, I have subclassed the UITextView and set the `canBecomeFirstResponder` to `NO` to block the keyboard & menu. Also I have disabled scrolling by `setScrollEnable:NO` and `setEditable:NO`

Comment: Also to add, I have tried setContentSize property with no luck.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you get this issue fixed?